# Excel Find & Mid functions for variable search tersm

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to return a string by searching through a cell with html tags, so for example this is the content of the cell:

AwardedFirm/Individual:<div class='col-sm-5''><div c Firm/Indass='row col-sm-12'>**TELECOMEGYPT (372679)**
(B7) Smart Village, 28th km Cairo-Alexandria desert road,Giza, Egypt<b ry: Egypt, Arab Republic of
**Signed Contract price**
EGP 29, 299,140.000
<d**Beneficial Ownership Details**

I would only like to return the value that comes after "Signed Contract Price" which is EGP 29,299,140.

I've tried to modify some "MID" formulas found online but to no avail. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML cells are in column A, then to extract the text between Signed Contract Price and "<dBeneficial Ownership Details", you can use this in column B:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID($A1,FIND("Signed Contract price",$A1,1)+LEN("Signed Contract price")+1,LEN($A1)),"<dBeneficial Ownership Details","")
```

To extract the currency code from that, you can use this in column C:

```
=LEFT(B1,3)
```

And to extract the amount itself, you can use this in column D:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-4)," ",""))
```

[image]

EDIT: I suppose the cell text got reformatted when you pasted it into your post, so it's better to enclose it in a code block, like this:

```
class='spacing'></div><div class='spacing'></div><div class='row col-sm-12'><div class='col-sm-5''><div c Firm/Indass='row col-sm-12'><b>TELECOMEGYPT (372679)</b><br/>(B7) Smart Village, 28th km Cairo-Alexandria desert road,Giza, Egypt<b ry: Egypt, Arab Republic of<br/></br></div></div><div class='col-sm-5'></div><div class='col-sm-7'>Signed Contractprice<br/>EGP 29, 299,140.000</div><br/></div><d<b>Beneficial Ownership Details</b></div><br/></div>
```

In this case, the first formula should be this:

```
=LEFT(MID($A1,FIND("Signed Contractprice<br/>",$A1,1)+LEN("Signed Contractprice<br/>"),LEN($A1)),FIND("</div>",MID($A1,FIND("Signed Contractprice<br/>",$A1,1)+LEN("Signed Contractprice<br/>"),LEN($A1)),1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying! I tried this and got an error message. :( This is the most of the text on the cell:
class='spacing'></div><div class='spacing'></div><div class='row col-sm-12'><div class='col-sm-5''><div c Firm/Indass='row col-sm-12'><b>TELECOMEGYPT (372679)</b><br/>(B7) Smart Village, 28th km Cairo-Alexandria desert road,Giza, Egypt<b ry: Egypt, Arab Republic of<br/></br></div></div><div class='col-sm-5'></div><div class='col-sm-7'>Signed Contractprice<br/>EGP 29, 299,140.000</div><br/></div><d<b>Beneficial Ownership Details</b></div><br/></div>

Comment: Ok, no worries. Please see the edit to my answer.